# Can't unset Trello card cover color using api

Tags: api, trello

We use trello cover color to indicate roles.
If cover color changed without authority it should be changed back.
I tried to simulate this using postman and following request, but it is not working:

```
PUT https://api.trello.com/1/cards/<card id>?token=<token>&key=<key>
Accept: application/json
---------- Body ----------------

{"cover":{"color": null}}
```

this also not working:

```
{"cover":{"color": ""}}
```

yellow cover color in output:

```
{
    "cover": {
        "color": "yellow",
    },
}
```

I tried using different color from api, it works, but i can't UNSET color.
[image: possible values]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine:

```
{"cover": ""}
```